# why this sql query doesn't work in python?

Tags: python, sql, database, web2py

I've a function `findParent` that takes a string, compares it with something else in `db` and returns another string. I wrote this in a .py file.

```
products=db(findParent(db.product_info.source_place)==auth.user.place).select()
```

The problem is, `db.product_info.source_place` doesn't etract `source_place` from `db` but instead sends the string itself i.e. `findParent` recieves `db.product_info.source_place` but not the corresponding value from the `db`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python does not support sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are comparing two fields in case like:

```
products=db(table1.field1==table2.field2).select()
```

It return a table after applying the join on these two fields.
When you use `findParent(db.product_info.source_place)`, the `findParent` is just considering as string `db.product_info.source_place` because it is not actually called for all the rows in the tables and called once and evaluated and then all rows of the `auth.user` are compared with that return value for the place column.

Solution added:

rows=db(db.product_info).select(db.product_info.source_place)
listwantedsource=[]
for row in rows:
listwantedsource.append(findParent(row.source_place))
products=db(auth.user.place.belongs(listwantedsource)).select()

Comment: there has be some way

Comment: I have added a solution for this.